# Asking something from a busy colleague

Tags: internship, deadlines

I'm an intern working at a software company. I have been here for a few months now, and my internship is coming to an end. My school requires feedback forms from people I have worked directly with during the time of my internship. These forms are quite extensive, and could take an hour to fill in (If not more). These feedback forms show the school how I have been doing during my internship, so they tackle subjects like 'Performance in Team' or 'The student works independent', just to give some examples.

I have worked with 2 people directly, the CEO of the company and the product owner of the team I was in. Recently, the product owner got assigned a new task, and is extremely busy. (Last day, he continued working until 11pm).

I have asked both if they wanted to fill in the form, and they both agreed. Today, I received the form from my CEO, but my product owner hasn't filled in anything yet. I assumed it was because he's very busy. When I asked him yesterday if he could fill it in tomorrow (Today) he apologized for being late, and promised to fill it in first thing tomorrow.

I haven't received anything at the time of writing this, and my deadline is coming up. It isn't a possibility to ask someone else, since they were the only 2 people I worked directly with. I also don't want to bother him too much, since he's already pretty stressed out.

What would be the best course of action to do? I don't want to annoy people here, but I do have that deadline coming up...

Edit: I forgot to mention the deadline for me handing in the report was supposed to be today. I have sent a mail to school asking if it's possible to hand it in later.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hand in the form that was filled out by the CEO and let your school know that the product owner is super busy and that you are working on him to hand in the form.

This is real life. Artificial school deadlines are not necessarily meaningful to those who have real life issues to deal with. I am pretty confident that your school understands your predicament.

Keep working on the product owner. Tell him that you already communicated to your school that it's going to take a little more time before his form gets handed in but please, he has to take one hour out of his life and fill out the damn form. And if he does it, he won't have to deal with it again.

Comment: Yeah I agree. Especially the last statement, I understand someone can be busy, but one hour out of his time will help me out. I'll contact my school about this, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Submit whatever you have and tell your school you are still waiting on the second feedback form. It's not your fault if your evaluation is late, your school will not hold that against  you.
You can copy the product owner on the email so that they can email the form directly to your school once they are done with it.

Answer (score 2):

You could help out by filling in the form yourself and getting him read it over quickly and suggest any edits/clarifications.  A quick scan/redo/sign should get this over and done with without slowing him up too much.

Comment: I can't fill it in myself since it's a feedback form. They have to 'grade' my performance during my internship. I'll clarify it in my post.

Comment: I meant for you to start filling it in on his behalf...  You should have a fairly good idea of how he thinks of you so far....

Comment: Oh I see where you're coming from. Problem is that I have no clue how he thinks about me, I realise how stupid that sounds. With 'working directly' I basically mean that I have reported to him on a weekly basis.

Comment: Make it generic then.  Your college will be looking for something broadly positive, showing a good work ethic, supply examples of where you've done good work, etc.  This will be good practice for when you may need to write self-assessment forms later in life...